# Pandas analysis of a network

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, graph, neural-network

I have a csv with two columns that basically represent a symmetrical connection between two points in a graph. So a point number can be in the each column. I'm trying to write a script to calculate the degree for each node obtained through these connections and plot the distribution of these degrees to study hubs concentration.

For some reason, I cannot use the networkx module implemented in Python or the script that it is an API for a ML software does not work. From previous trials, I know that the pandas module was fully supported, so my previous scripts do not work.

Comment: Welcome to SO Giano! Can you clarify the issue with `networkx`, include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried so far, and an example of the expected output?